# Memcached dynamic feed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, memcached

I have a dynamic feed of events from users that are being followed by the current user, the partials are all memcached, but I'd also like to do it for the feed itself. My concern is that if I memcache this that it will show the same thing for every user based on the first write to cache rather than being dynamic for each unique user.

How would I memcache the feed and @following? How do I have it update if the current user follows another user? I'm assuming I can't just wrap it with a <% cache "feed" do %>

NOTE: using Memcached and Dalli

```
<% @following = current_user.following.collect {|f| f["id"]} %>
<div class='content'>
<% unless Rsvp.where(:voter_id => @following, :status => 'going').where("start_time > ? AND start_time < ?", Time.now, Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59.000000')).order("count_all desc").count(:group => :event_id).collect { |f| f[0] }.count == 0 %>
          <div class='date_bar_container'><div class='date_bar'>Today</div></div>
          <div class='content_wrapper'>
    <%= render :partial => 'events/event', :collection => Event.where(:id =>  Rsvp.where(:event_id => Rsvp.where(:voter_id => @following, :status => 'going').where("start_time > ? AND start_time < ?", Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00.000000'), Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59.000000')).order("count_all desc").count(:group => :event_id).collect { |f| f[0] }).select("DISTINCT event_id").collect(&:event_id)).order('start_time asc')%>
          </div>
<% end %>

<% unless Rsvp.where(:voter_id => @following, :status => 'going').where("start_time > ? AND start_time < ?", (Time.now + 1.day).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00.000000'), (Time.now + 1.day).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59.000000')).order("count_all desc").count(:group => :event_id).collect { |f| f[0] }.count == 0%>
          <div class='date_bar_container'><div class='date_bar'>Tomorrow</div></div>
          <div class='content_wrapper'>
    <%= render :partial => 'events/event', :collection => Event.where(:id =>  Rsvp.where(:event_id => Rsvp.where(:voter_id => @following, :status => 'going').where("start_time > ? AND start_time < ?", (Time.now + 1.day).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00.000000'), (Time.now + 1.day).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59.000000')).order("count_all desc").count(:group => :event_id).collect { |f| f[0] }).select("DISTINCT event_id").collect(&:event_id)).order('start_time asc')%>
    </div>
    <% end %>

<% (2..15).each do |f| %>
    <% unless Rsvp.where(:voter_id => @following, :status => 'going').where("start_time > ? AND start_time < ?", (Time.now + f.day).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00.000000'), (Time.now + f.day).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59.000000')).order("count_all desc").count(:group => :event_id).collect { |f| f[0] }.count == 0 %>
              <div class='date_bar_container'><div class='date_bar'><%= dayofweek((Time.now + f.day).wday) %>, <%= month((Time.now + f.day).month) %> <%= (Time.now + f.day).day %>, 2012</div></div>
              <div class='content_wrapper'>
        <%= render :partial => 'events/event', :collection => Event.where(:id =>  Rsvp.where(:event_id => Rsvp.where(:voter_id => @following, :status => 'going').where("start_time > ? AND start_time < ?", (Time.now + f.day).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00.000000'), (Time.now + f.day).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59.000000')).order("count_all desc").count(:group => :event_id).collect { |f| f[0] }).select("DISTINCT event_id").collect(&:event_id)).order('start_time asc')%>
         </div>
        <% end %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unrelated, but that is way too much model code / sql in your views. Package them up in class methods or scopes.

With regards to the caching if you don't want every user to see the same thing then you need to make the cache key different for each user. One way of doing this is to pass the `action_suffix` option, which adds to the data used to generate the cache key (by default it's just controller and action). If you include the current user id as part of this then caching will be done on a per user basis. You can also pass in a string with an arbitrary cache key to user rather than have it built up from controller, action and action suffix.

Cache expiry is said to be one of the 2 difficult things in computer science. There are at least 3 options:

- When you cache something, set the expires_in to an appropriate timespan. When the underlying  data changes do nothing: you accept that what the user sees may be out of date by up to the timespan you set. Set it high and they'll see stale data for a long time, set it too low and you'll be throwing away cache data that could have been kept.

eg:

```
 <% cache({:action_suffix => 'blah'}, :expires_in => 20.minutes  do %>
  ..
 <% end %>
```

- Explicitly expire the data in response to model changes, for example via a sweeper. It can be tricky to remember all the the places this could happen and to remember to augment the sweeper when you add new stuff
- Use generational cache keys: structure your cache key so that when the underlying data changes the cache key will also change. A very simple example would be if you were caching a page of information about a user. You could set the cache key to `user_#{user.id}_#{user.updated_at.to_i}` (or equivalently, `user.cache_key` ). When the user changes, no matter how, then the cache key you use changes too (because the `updated_at` will have changed) and so you'll not use the old cache data

Comment: Instead of using `"user_#{user.id}_#{user.updated_at.to_i}"` you can just use the built-in `cache_key` method. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/cache_key See the third example on the page.